# How can I run php once a form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

When submitting the search form (search & view inventory), the data for the search isn't passed through, so I assume the easiest thing to do would be to have the php run on the same page as the search form and just pass the variable on. This is my current code that displays the results, and the search form is just a simple html form that posts the "search":

```
<?php

$search = $_GET['search'];
if ($search == "") {
    echo "Please enter a query. <a href='/search.php'>Click Here</a> to go back";
  break;
}
else {
$data = array('key' => $API_KEY /*Ignore this*/,
              /*'consignorId' => '1',*/
              'query' => $search,
              'includeItemsWithQuantityZero' => 'false');

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => "Accept: application/json\r\n".
          "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
    'content' => $data_string
  )
));

$result = file_get_contents('https://user.traxia.com/app/api/inventory', false, $context);


$jsonData = $result;
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$phpArray = $phpArray['results'];
$activeonly = array_filter($phpArray, function($active) { return $status['status']=="ACTIVE"; });
$mykeys = array('name','sku','category','color','size','currentPrice');
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/test/css/search-results.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/js/tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script> 
</head>
<div class="CSSTableGenerator"> 
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <?php
        foreach($mykeys as $k) {
            if ($k == "name") {
              $k = "Name";
            }
            if ($k == "sku") {
              $k = "SKU";
            }
            if ($k == "category") {
              $k = "Category";
            }
            if ($k == "color") {
              $k = "Color";
            }
            if ($k == "size") {
              $k = "Size";
            }
            if ($k == "currentPrice") {
              $k = "Price";
            }
            echo "<th style='cursor:pointer'>$k<img src='/test/images/UpDown.png' width='8px' height='auto' style='margin: 0px 20px'></th>";
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($phpArray as $key => $values) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach($mykeys as $k) {
                if ($values['category'] == 'UNCATEGORIZED') continue;
                $value = $k == "currentPrice" ? '$' . number_format($values[$k]/100,'2') : $values[$k];
                echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

Is this the easiest way or would there be something easier? Thanks!

Comment: Is `user.traxia.com` the same domain as the search page? If so, you can use AJAX on the search page.

Comment: user.traxia.com is where the search request is where the data comes from if that's what you mean...

Comment: Then you can do what you want with AJAX. I was just making sure you wouldn't run into a cross-domain problem.